# How to get event string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm writing some Javascript that triggers a function when a div is clicked and then prints the name of the event that triggers it so I have:

```
$('#areaOne').on('show.bs.collapse', onAreaClick);

function onAreaClick(){
    console.log(this.id + ' ' + event.trigger)
}
```

However when I run this I get 'areaOne undefined' when I'd like 'areaOne show.bs.collapse'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [handleObj event property](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-extensions/#the-handleobj-object) will expose all you need BUT you have to pass `event` as handler parameter because, e.g, FF doesn't use global event model:

```
$('#areaOne').on('show.bs.collapse', onAreaClick);

function onAreaClick(e){
    console.log(this.id + ' ' + e.handleObj.type + '.' + e.handleObj.namespace)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first reference the event argument, and then you probably wanted the event type

```
$('#areaOne').on('show.bs.collapse', onAreaClick);

function onAreaClick(evt){
    console.log(this.id + ' ' + evt.namespace + '-' + evt.type)
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/R6EAW/4236/)

Comment: What about namespace?

Comment: @A.Wolff - should be accessible directly on the event

Comment: Not in all cases: http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/4237/  Now it depends what OP is expecting. At least, `hanldeObj.namespace` returns `Namespace(s), if any, provided when the event was attached`: http://jsfiddle.net/R6EAW/4238/

Comment: @A.Wolff - you're right, if you trigger the event without using the namespace, you won't get the original namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#areaOne').on('show.bs.collapse', onAreaClick);

function onAreaClick(event) {
    console.log(this.id + ' ' + event.trigger)
}
```

edit: adeneo's answer is correct.